# How to assign LWin to click and be able to use LWin + other keys at the same time

Tags: autohotkey

need to assign LWin to LMB click. At the same time I want to use LWin + WASD as arrows.
I tried following code. Not working.

```
#w::Up ; the same for A,S,D
LWin::SendInput {Click}
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already got answer from AutoHotKey forum. Just need to add tilde to 2nd line.

```
#w::Up ; the same for A,S,D
~LWin::SendInput {Click}
```

Thanks to AutoHotKey users!